# Match closest date from a table to a table with just dates

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.7, date

I am trying to feel some gaps in table with values from a previous date.
I have created a date table which looks like this:

| date |
| --- |
| 2021-04-13 |
| 2021-04-14 |
| 2021-04-15 |
| 2021-04-16 |
| 2021-04-17 |
| 2021-04-18 |
| 2021-04-19 |
| 2021-04-20 |

And main table which looks like this:

| capture_date | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-14 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 2.99 |
| 2021-04-16 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.03 |
| 2021-04-17 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.05 |
| 2021-04-20 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.04 |

And the main result i want to achieve is this:

| date | capture_date | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 | 2021-04-13 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-14 | 2021-04-14 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 2.99 |
| 2021-04-15 | 2021-04-14 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 2.99 |
| 2021-04-16 | 2021-04-16 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.03 |
| 2021-04-17 | 2021-04-17 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.05 |
| 2021-04-18 | 2021-04-17 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.05 |
| 2021-04-19 | 2021-04-17 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.05 |
| 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-20 | Electronic Arts Inc. | 3.04 |

I have made a query that does this:

```
SELECT c.date, e.capture_date, company, value FROM `calendar` c
INNER JOIN companies e ON
e.capture_date = (SELECT e1.capture_date
                  FROM companies e1
                  WHERE e1.capture_date <= c.date
                  ORDER BY capture_date DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
WHERE e.company='Electronic Arts Inc.';
```

However for a company like:

| capture_date | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |

The same query is giving me this result:

| date | capture_date | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |

When I need this:

| date | capture_date | company | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-13 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-14 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-15 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-16 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-17 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-18 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-19 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |
| 2021-04-20 | 2021-04-13 | Apple | 3.01 |

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: the design is very bad and i guss evry solution presented will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

1. Take a date from the calendar
2. Take a row from the table which is not above the date from the calendar
3. Ensure that there is no another row in the table with the date between the  dates from steps 1 and 2 (which' date is above the date taken on the step 2 but not above than the date taken on the step 1)

So this will be

```
SELECT *
FROM calendar t1
JOIN datatable t2 ON t1.date >= t2.date
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM datatable t3
                   WHERE t1.date >= t3.date
                     AND t3.date > t2.date )
```

---

**UPDATE**

The code was updated. The names of tables/columns used are taken from the question. The condition which allows to select one company from a lot of companies in the table added.

Query text:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM calendar t1
JOIN companies t2 ON t1.`date` >= t2.capture_date
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM companies t3
                   WHERE t1.`date` >= t3.capture_date
                     AND t3.capture_date > t2.capture_date
                     AND t2.company = t3.company )
  AND t2.company = @company_name;
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c090864a4412a6ba8c9546fbb3694c20)

Comment: It gives the same result as the query in my code.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! The updated version gave me the right result.